# pandas OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I try to read a excel file using pandas with the code below:

`path = "QVI_transaction_data.xlsx"`

I also tried using "./QVI_transaction_data.xlsx" rather than the one above, the name is just copy pasted from os.listdir() so there is no transcription problems

`pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = "in")`

but it didn't worked, it outputs this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I also tried without the sheet_name argument, others posts say that there is a problem with the filename but I had worked with pandas before and I don't think there is something wrong with the name. anyone knows what is wrong about this?

this is how the file looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the explicit path for `path = "QVI_transaction_data.xlsx" `  like it may have `path = "\home\QVI_transaction_data.xlsx" ` or `path = "/home/QVI_transaction_data.xlsx" `,  or better if you  could show us how you are reading the file from Directory path?

Comment: I am using colab, this is the path, /content/QVI_transaction_data.xlsx" I also tried using old python notebook on my pc having the same error

Comment: using the full path I also get the same error

Comment: Do you have a particular sheet name which you are trying to read? if so then pls make sure you are using right name.

Comment: yes, the sheet name is "in", I used it

Comment: Okay, can you try like `df = pd.read_excel(r'/content/QVI_transaction_data.xlsx',  sheet_name = 'in')`,  does it complain about `xlrd`? if yes, then you can do `import xlrd`.  or maybe you can try in case version issue `df = pd.read_excel(r'/content/QVI_transaction_data.xlsx',  sheet_name = 'in', engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: Is there a possibility to share that file somewhere to reproduced?

Comment: What i sence from the Error code , you are using old version of python , you should try `df = pd.read_excel(path, sheetname=in)`

Comment: @KarnKumar: you mean older (pre-0.21) version of pandas. Not of Python.

Comment: @smci, oh yes. i forgot to mention pandas, thx for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing that could be done is to convert the excel file (.xlsx) file to .csv file which can be done through file and export it with csv file and then it could be loaded like: -

```
import pandas as pd
Data=pd.read_csv("File Name...")
print(Data)
```

Or if you want to load only the excel file directly this could be done: -

```
import pandas as pds
file =('path_of_excel_file')
newData = pds.read_excel(file)
newData
```

Comment: changing the file extension didn't work too and read_excel is the function i am using but I also tried with ExcelFile

Comment: i tried working with your file for more clarification i was able to run both in form of excel and as well as csv

Comment: For reading the excel try this: -

Comment: make sure for reading the excel file try importing (import pandas as pds) and not pd it will work if you import pandas as pds

Comment: and make sure you change \ to /

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in the both possible ways in form of csv and as well as excel. Try something like this: -

```
import pandas as pds
file =('path_of_excel_file')
newData = pds.read_excel(file)
newData
```

Comment: @L Prathyusha , Reading Excel files may have issues if the `xlrd` or `openpyxl` is running old on the system.

Comment: one more possiblity is that to read the file like this: - `Data=pd.read_csv("File Name..."r)` by putting 'r' at the end of the code it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

As we can not have Data to reproduce, hence there might be different situation and different solutions.

I'm enlisting few situations which may lead you in a right direction...

### Situation 1:

If you are using old python Version, then you should try simply below as its `sheetname` with older version and `sheet_name` with new version.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(file_with_data, sheetname=sheet_with_data)
```

OR

You can use `pd.ExcelFile` instead ..

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'in')
```

OR

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
# xl = pd.ExcelFile("Full_Path_of _file")

xl.sheet_names
[u'in', u'in1', u'in2']
df = xl.parse("in")
df.head()
```

OR

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('your_xls_xlsx_filename','rb'), sheet_name='Sheet 1')
# or using sheet index starting 0
df = pd.read_excel(open('your_xls_xlsx_filename','rb'), sheet_name=1)
```

**Note:** Opting sheetname argument needs be opted meticulously for python pandas version-wise>

For Older python Version: use `sheetname`

For New python version: use `sheet_name`

### Situation 2:

Copy the address directly from the right-click file properties-security will cause this problem So, copying and pasting the file path also produce these issues while there is no other evident issues

**solve**

```
It has nothing to do with the backslash /forward slash in the path, and it has nothing to do with whether the path contains. There are two solutions

1 Enter the path manually
2 Open this path in Explorer, then copy
```

### General reading convention:

```
# When the parameter is None, all tables are returned, which is a dictionary of tables;
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name= None)
# When the parameter is list = [0, 1, 2, 3], the returned multi-table is also a dictionary
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name= 0)
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name= [0,1])
#The data of the table can also be read according to the name of the table header or the position of the table
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name= 'Sheet0')
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name= ['Sheet0','Sheet1'])
sheet = pd.read_excel('example.xls',sheet_name=[0,1,'Sheet3'])
```

Comment: When the OP isn't clear, ask them clarifications, and close the question if they still won't provide them. Better than an answer speculating about multiple causes. This one wasn't about the path.

Comment: @smci, agreed.. will keep a note.